# R: What does dplyr stand for

Tags: r, dplyr

[dplyr](https://www.r-bloggers.com/data-manipulation-with-dplyr/) is an R package for data manipulation.

But what does dplyr stand for?

(I think 'd' stands for data.)

Comment: Is it derived from http://www.dictionary.com/browse/plyer

Comment: `d` is for `data.frame`, `plyr` as in a set of pliers to manipulate things with. `dplyr` is a data.frame specific set of tools like [`plyr`](http://plyr.had.co.nz/).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From [dplyr github](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/1857):

> The d is for dataframes, the plyr is to evoke pliers. Pronounce however you like.